# ios - creating functions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, function

I know what a function is, but I am trying to write a few into my project. I have just watched a video series on Objective-C from Lynda.com where I got the idea from.

In the video is it is explained that I can write a function like this:

```
void declareWebView ()
```

However if I write it like that into my code, the error comes up and says that my _webView and self (as self.view) are not available.

if I write it like this:

```
-(void) declareWebView
```

Then I do not have an issue.

Any ideas on how to get the first one right?
As far as I can tell, I cannot set any parameters with the second way of writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is as you said called a function. It is part of the C part of Objective-C, and is not connected to objects or classes, so the variable `self` or any instance variables of an object don't have any meaning. You can pass it variables that are objects though like so:

```
void my_func(NSString *string, id someObject, int someInt);

void my_func(NSString *string, id someObject, int someInt)
{
    NSLog(@"string = %@, someObject = %@, someInt = %d",string,someObject,someInt);
}
```

The second is a method, and in a  method you can access self and, within instance methods, access instance variables. Replacing the "-" in front of the method with a "+" makes it a class method. In a class method you can't access instance variables and `self` refers to the class itself, not an instance.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first way is written in the language C. The second way is written in Objective-C. Objective-C methods must be declared the second way. You cannot access your object's private members and properties from within a C function directly, but you could use accessor methods on the Objective-C object and call them from a C function.

Comment: Cool that sorts it, I will stick with the second one then :-)